# Microsoft Form Update System

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm working on creating a Front End for multiple users for MS Access, and I have come up with a method to update their forms if there are any changes that need to be made. Basically what my VBA code will do, is delete the old forms and import the new ones if there are any (approximately 10 forms).

There is one issue with my process... Every time a new form is being imported, it is asking the user to accept the security warning and it gets annoying when there are so many forms and sometimes it can be a lengthy process to sit and wait for each to import and click accept every time a new import comes in.

Is there a more logical way to do this? Does Access have a build in function that will detect any changes to a form and update it based on a separate database?

```
Private Function PullNewForms()

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
                           "LOCATION", _
                           acForm, "frmLogin", "frmLogin"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
                           "LOCATIONb", _
                           acForm, "frmNewUser", "frmNewUser"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
                           "LOCATION", _
                           acForm, "frmOptionsMenu", "frmOptionsMenu"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
                           "LOCATION, _
                           acForm, "frmResetPassword", "frmResetPassword"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
                           "LOCATION", _
                           acForm, "frmVendorMainForm", "frmVendorMainForm"

End Function
```

Can this be consolidated to one line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconsider this current setup. You should not be importing application objects like *forms*, *reports*, even *modules* on the fly like this as corruption and crashing may occur. You need a more stable version control system among your user base. Only data should ever really be imported.

Consider the following when deploying an MS Access FrontEnd application to multiple users:

1. Give each user their own FrontEnd to run on their local machines.
2. Keep a Master FrontEnd on a shared network that they can all access but never directly use, still maintaining the split architecture:

   [image: Split Architecture Diagram]
3. Give each user their own batch file (.bat) that they can double click from their desktops or wherever to copy the latest Master FrontEnd to replace their older version.
4. Keep for yourself, the developer, a development FrontEnd copy that when tested and debugged and ready to deploy into production, you replace as the new Master FrontEnd. This is hard at first but try not to make development changes in Master or local copies since you may overwrite your own changes.
5. Finally, with every new form/report/macro/module change, inform every user of a new available FrontEnd and to have them simply click their batch file to replace previous version.

**Batch** file

*(Save below text in Notepad but as a .bat file and not default .txt file which automatically makes it a double-click executable script with gear icon. Give each user their own batch file tailoring local paths accordingly and save to their desktop or wherever their FrontEnd is located)*

```
@echo off

Copy "\\Server\Path\To\MasterFrontEnd.accdb" "C:\User\JaneDoe\LocalFrontEnd.accdb" /Y

start "" cmd /c "echo UPDATE COMPLETE!&echo(&pause"
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, and I love the idea... however this was something that I tried in the past and I had an issue when copying from a Network drive with a batch file. I'll see if I can replicate this issue for you again, unfortunately however I am not at the office right now and I wont be able to check until Tuesday next week.

Comment: Try saving it as a cmd file - windows 10 will run those quite happily, but I have seen issues with .bat files for some inexplicable reason.